# What does "alternate tone or mood" exactly means in <i> tag definition in HTML 5?

Tags: html

In the [docs(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em#:%7E:text=alternate%20tone%20or%20mood), it is written:"Use the  element to mark text that is in an **alternate tone or mood**, which covers many common situations for italics such as scientific names or words in other languages".

What does "alternate tone or mood" means in the above definition? Can someone explain it in simple terms.
It would be quite helpful if someone can explain this by providing an example.

Comment: Do you know what a [*tone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)) is?

Comment: The [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) itself has a longer definition and also some useful examples. Did you take a look at them? Do you have specific questions about them?

Comment: @shank: is your question answered?  When you state a fact ("The sky is blue"), your "tone" is "flat".  If you want to stress that it's a really beautiful day, you might "emphasize" the word "blue" ("The sky is *blue*).  This is an example of "altnerating tone".  Using "italics" is one way to convey "tone" in HTML.  Using the `<em>` tag is a good way to do this.  Q: Does that help?

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps a good way to answer your question is from the same reference:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em
>
> New developers are often confused at seeing multiple elements that
> produce similar results. `<em>` and `<i>` are a common example, since
> they both italicize text. What's the difference? Which should you use?
>
> By default, the visual result is the same. However, the semantic
> meaning is different. The `<em>` element represents stress emphasis of
> its contents, while the `<i>` element represents text that is set off
> from the normal prose, such a foreign word, fictional character
> thoughts, or when the text refers to the definition of a word instead
> of representing its semantic meaning. (The title of a work, such as
> the name of a book or movie, should use `<cite>`.)
>
> This means the right one to use depends on the situation. Neither is
> for purely decorational purposes, that's what CSS styling is for.

To ["emphasize"](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/emphasize) something is to express "alternate tone or mood".

If you want to "emphasize" a certain word or phrase in a paragraph, you can use [italics](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/italicize).

In editors like MS-Word, you can highlight the text, and select "Italicize".
Older versions of HTML provided the `<i>` element.  HTML 5 introduced the "semantic" equivalent, `<em>`.  Distinguishing it from other semantic elements, like `<cite>`.

Comment: Actually, `em` was introduced in HTML 4.01. I think the examples that follow the quoted text are probably good material for the OP as well.

Comment: -1 for "*To "emphasize" something is to express "alternate tone or mood".*" That's exactly *not* the same meaning, which is why there are separate tags for the two cases, as explained in the text you quoted. They are not semantically equivalent.

Comment: Screen readers may read `i` and `em` differently, which could be a determining factor in choosing one or the other. Remembering to factor in the experience of people who access your site different is important.

Comment: To "emphasize" (in the English sense of the word) is *exactly* to "express an alternate tone or mood.  For example, I wanted to "emphasize" to word "exactly".  !?!DO YOU HEAR ME?!?"  To give another example of "alternate tone or mood" ;)  BTW: I would argue that using `<i>` should be *discouraged*, in favor of `<em>` or `<cite>`.  To italicize or not should be the province of CSS, not HTML markup.

Comment: @paulsm4 The dictionary you linked says "*To emphasize is to make something important, or stress it, or give extra weight to it.*" It has nothing to do with tone or mood. (And in this very comment, I did `<i>`talicise the quote because it should stand apart, and would be read with a different voice, not because I wanted to emphasise it).

Comment: @HereticMonkey `<em>` is much older that HTML 4.01. It was part of [HTML 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt#:~:text=start-tag:%20EM)